# CakePHP object converting to array?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to display names instead of ids on one of my tables.
I have a **WorkRequest** which has many **WorkRequestChecks** of each **Checkbox**.

These are my table create statements

```
CREATE TABLE `work_requests` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `work_request_checks` (
  `work_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `checkbox_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`work_request_id`,`checkbox_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `checkboxes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

From the **WorkRequest** page I am trying to show a list of **WorkRequestChecks** that have been entered. This is working fine apart from the fact it seems like cakephp isn't seeing the **WorkRequestCheck** as an object. It will display the ids of the **Checkbox** but when I try reference the ->name I get the error.

```
include - APP/Template/WorkRequests/view.ctp, line 193
Cake\View\View::_evaluate() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 1010
Cake\View\View::_render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 971
Cake\View\View::render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 595
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 623
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 125
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 93
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/BaseApplication.php, line 78
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php, line 59
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 93
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware::__invoke() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php, line 52
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
```

This is strange as I have this working on **WorkRequestChecks** index page as displayed below.
[image: WorkRequestChecks Index Page]

This a photo of the errors I get referencing **Checkbox** name on the **WorkRequests** page.
[image: WorkRequests View Page]

This is my code for my **WorkRequests** view.ctp relating the **WorkRequestChecks**

```
<?php foreach ($workRequest->work_request_checks as $Checks): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Html->link($Checks->checkbox->name, ['controller' => 'Checkboxes', 'action' => 'view', $Checks->checkbox->id])?></td>
        <td><?= h($Checks->value) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried printing the **$workRequest** object and this is the result

```
object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequest) {

    'id' => (int) 80590,
    'invoice_id' => (int) 21412009,
    'item' => '1',
    'defect' => 'Calibration Due',
    'model_no' => 'TE135 30dB Attenuator',
    'part_no' => 'SA4N50-30',
    'quantity' => '1',
    'serial_no' => 'NSN',
    'status_id' => '3',
    'worksheet_id' => 'WSCC',
    'remarks' => '',
    'mm' => '',
    'cal_cert_ref' => '0',
    'test_equipment_id' => '',
    'ATA_chapter' => '',
    'pub' => '0',
    'pub_last_controlled' => '',
    'test_harness_used' => '',
    'closed' => (int) 1,
    'work_request_checks' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 1,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 2,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 3,
            'value' => (int) 0,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 4,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 4 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 5,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 5 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 6,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 6 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 8,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 7 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 17,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        },
        (int) 8 => object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

            'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
            'checkbox_id' => (int) 19,
            'value' => (int) 1,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

        }
    ],
    'work_tasks' => [],
    'test_equipment' => null,
    'worksheet' => null,
    'status' => object(App\Model\Entity\Status) {

        'id' => (int) 3,
        'name' => 'Calibrated',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Statuses'

    },
    'invoice' => object(App\Model\Entity\Invoice) {

        'id' => (int) 21412009,
        'start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

            'time' => '2014-12-01T00:00:00+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'close_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

            'time' => '2014-12-01T00:00:00+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'invoice_to_id' => '1504',
        'contact_name' => '',
        'phone_number' => '',
        'aircraft_reg_id' => '',
        'ship_to_address' => '',
        'ship_via_id' => '89',
        'notes' => 'Item 1:  TE135 30DB ATTENUATOR  P/N: SA4N50-30  S/N: NSN.  Defect Reported:  Calibration Due., Calibration carried out and found serviceable.',
        'worksheet_notes' => 'Item 1:  TE135 30DB ATTENUATOR  P/N: SA4N50-30  S/N: NSN.  Defect Reported:  Calibration Due., Calibration carried out and found serviceable.',
        'closed' => true,
        'times_printed' => '1',
        'payment_due' => '1',
        'opening_notes' => '',
        'activity_counter' => '0',
        'last_viewed' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2014-12-15T08:24:00+13:45',
            'timezone' => 'NZ-CHAT',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'last_viewed_by_id' => '62',
        'courier_ticket_no' => '',
        'job_description' => 'Calibration',
        'spell_checked' => true,
        'authorisation_no' => '',
        'priority_id' => '',
        'job_type_id' => '',
        'opened_by_id' => '47',
        'assigned_to_id' => '47',
        'checked_out_to_id' => (int) 1,
        'exclued_from_unclosed_job_report' => false,
        'certification_required' => false,
        'requested_finish_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

            'time' => '2014-12-04T00:00:00+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'exclude_from_requested_finish_date' => false,
        'supervising_engineer_id' => '1',
        'quote_ref' => '1',
        'currency_id' => '1',
        'ent_MYOB' => true,
        'MYOB_amount' => '$113.85',
        'MYOB_batch' => '664',
        'exchange_rate' => '1',
        'payment_instructions_id' => '1',
        'invoice_emailed' => true,
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Invoices'

    },
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'WorkRequests'

}
```

Then I tried printing on of the **$Checks**

```
    object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

    'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
    'checkbox_id' => (int) 1,
    'value' => (int) 1,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'

}
```

This is my **WorkRequest** controller view method

```
public function view($id = null)
    {   
        $workRequest = $this->WorkRequests->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['WorkRequestChecks']
        ]);

        $this->set('workRequest', $workRequest);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['workRequest']);
```

Here's part of my **WorkRequestsTable**.php file

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('work_requests');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('WorkRequestChecks', [
            'foreignKey' => 'work_request_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Here's part of my **CheckboxesTable**.php file

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('checkboxes');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->belongsTo('CheckboxTypes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'checkbox_type_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Here's part of my **WorkRequestChecksTable**.php file
    public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            parent::initialize($config);

```
        $this->setTable('work_request_checks');
        $this->setDisplayField('work_request_id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['work_request_id', 'checkbox_id']);

        $this->belongsTo('WorkRequests', [
            'foreignKey' => 'work_request_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Checkboxes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'checkbox_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working; it seems like it's converted the object $Check to an array.

Comment: Please use `debug()` to dump objects, and make sure that the output is properly formatted, that `$workRequest` dump is completely unreadable.

Comment: @ndm thanks didn't know I could use debug() like that. :-)

Comment: `$Checks` is still an object, but it has no `checkbox` field, hence `->checkbox` will return `null`. You haven't contained the `Checkboxes` association.

Answer (score 0):

As in your CTP, you're trying to access $Checks->checkbox->name

But as your dump says, it contains just:

object(App\Model\Entity\WorkRequestCheck) {

```
'work_request_id' => (int) 80590,
'checkbox_id' => (int) 1,
'value' => (int) 1,
'[new]' => false,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'WorkRequestChecks'
```

}

So, there is no checkbox field at all and then will always be null and you'll get the error.
You need to associate it in your model if you want to retrieve data from a checkbox with id. Also check the recursive, you might want to change it to 1 or 2.

Comment: The only problem is work_requests not associated with the checkboxes only work_request_checks is. Is there a way in cakephp I could display the names from checkboxes without creating an association to work_requests?

Comment: You can use a find on the checkboxes, but I wouldn't recommend that, even though I already did it. This way you can parse id as the value and the name as the label, but it is really easy to associate it.

Comment: Alright got it working using a function in my checkboxes controller to find all the checkbox objects and called it in my work requests view ctp. Seems a bit messy but it works thanks!